# No result while printing collections in python using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

After I execute:

```
customer = collection.find(projection= something)
```

I try to print data present in customer, but rather shows blank. I'm not able to understand why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a pymongo.cursor.Cursor into a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968660/how-to-convert-a-pymongo-cursor-cursor-into-a-dict)

Comment: it might not be able to find the data?? that is why it is blank you need to write proper mongodb query statement read the mongodb query guide