# search through all collections of a database in Mongodb (python)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How to search all the collections of a database-name: `test` for a word having `length` say `6`

The sample data in collections is like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e0983863bcf0dab51f2872b"
    },
    "word": "never",
    "wordset_id": "a42b50e85e",
    "meanings": [{
        "id": "1f1bca9d9f",
        "def": "not ever",
        "speech_part": "adverb",
        "synonyms": ["ne'er"]
    }, {
        "id": "d35f973ed0",
        "def": "not at all",
        "speech_part": "adverb"
    }]
}
```

How can I query for all words with `length` of `6` across all collections of `test`?

I have tried this way but it is giving only first collection results:

```
@app.......
def fn():
    collections=db.collection_names()
    for collection in collections:
        data = db[collection].aggregate([
            {
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {"$eq": [{"$strLenCP": "$word"}, n]}
                }
            }
        ])
    return render_template('lettersearch.html',data=data)
```

when I am printing data I get all cursors as:

```
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000258F4F5B470>
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000258F4F76BA8>
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000258F4F6E5F8>
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000258F4F8A6A0>
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000258F4F8E048>
```

How to iterate over these objects and render in template as `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to search all the collections of a database

You can achieve this in two steps:

1. Retrieve all collections in the database - `db.getCollectionNames()`
2. For each collection run the query below

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [
                    {
                        $strLenCP: "$word"
                    },
                    6
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: 2) point , after getting all collections how can I run query for each collection?

Comment: You can use this `db["yourCollectionName"].aggregate()`. @Codenewbie

Comment: Thanks a ton matet, only thing i want to overwrite in your answer is `db.list_collection_names()` to retrieve all collections

Comment: I think it is Python version, mine is `mongo shell` version. @Codenewbie

Comment: Any guiding link to mongo query examples?

Comment: Check out mongodb docs, it has example for every command. @Codenewbie

Comment: one more question, how do you iterate over all collections the above query ? when I am trying i just get the result for first collection

Comment: Store your collections in a list (i.e. collections). Then, define a for loop `for collection in collections: db[collection].aggregate([])`

Comment: updated in my question , did i do something wrong there?

Comment: when I try to print the `data` above i am getting all `cursor objects` , updated in my question , how can I loop over them and pass all `data` in to `dataall` variable to render in template?

Comment: Is there a way to do that mate, i have been stuck here

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968660/how-to-convert-a-pymongo-cursor-cursor-into-a-dict, or consider asking a new question. @Codenewbie

Answer (score 1):

For each collection use [$strLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) with this aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {$eq: [{$strLenCP: "$word"}, 6]}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Does it search all collections of db or should i have to mention collection name?

Comment: no, theres no such thing as searching all of the collections - you will have to change it to something like `db.getCollection("collection_name").aggregate`

Comment: mate , how to query such that get all results having `speech_part`="adverb" for eg