# How to wait pymongo find() results without looping all rows?

Tags: python, pymongo

Not getting any result in pymongo by find() function in my collection:

[image]

But if I loop that variable, then it loads:

[image]

The only thing I did is adding a loop (see line ):

```
    for row in local_data:
        print(row)
```

So if I put that loop it will load all rows and I will see retrieved: 46

How can I wait it to return results without looping like that? Something like `mycollection.find().Wait()`

Comment: Can you please include the code of question as plain text?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968660/how-to-convert-a-pymongo-cursor-cursor-into-a-dict/28970776.

Comment: I can't share the code, but it's a simple mongodb.collection.find() instruction like any other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` returns an iterable cursor. You have to iterate it (e.g. with a for loop) to get the results. If you don't iterate it, it doesn't do anything.

You can wrap the find in a `list()` command that will create a list of returned documents.