# Error <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x106177a60>

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I would like some help with this code, I can't get a return through Pycharm, only if I open the container and run the command directly in mongosh.

My code:

```
connect = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
base = connect["base_test"]
mycol = base["users"]
print(mycol.find())

<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x106177a60>
```

My docker-compose:

```
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_db:/data/db
    container_name: mongo_db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo_db:27017/
    container_name: mongo_express
```

in the mongo shell the call works:

```
base_test> db.users.find()
[ { _id: ObjectId("63498015bafdd447d73784fb"), name: 'Guilherme' } ]
```

my code in `for`:

```
connect = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
base = connect["base_test"]
mycol = base["users"]
cur = mycol.find()
for doc in cur:
    print(doc)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PycharmProjects/SSE.py", line 12, in <module>
    for doc in mycol:
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not iterable
```

But in pymongo it's giving this cursor error, and when I put it inside `for`, it says it's not iterable. Help me please.

Comment: A `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` *should* be iterable, see [this answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28970776/7867968). Can you show us the exact code you are using in the for loop that raises the exception?

Comment: There is no error being shown here, you are simply printing out an object that doesn't have a particularly useful string representation.

Comment: I tried doing it this way and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo; it should be:

```
for doc in cur:
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Sorry, but even fixing the error, does not return any value, I do not know what happens.

Comment: Double check you have specified the right server, database and collection.

Comment: Try setting your connection string to `"mongodb://mongo_db:27017/"`

Comment: I tried to change the connection by putting the name of the bank and it gave an error, I checked the code and everything is ok, I wanted to be able to film and show what happens.

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: so that's the problem, none, it doesn't print anything it just returns None.

Comment: I'm going to guess you have another database somewhere and you are connecting to the wrong one. As a test, use pymongo to add a record before running the find. If the find still returns no records, something is wrong with the code. If it does find the record, use mongosh to see if you can see it in your database. This should help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Perfect, I deleted the mongo I had on my computer because I had installed it a long time ago, and it only worked with docker mongo. Thank you very much.